Fabric Dynamic Binary Content
I have secure storage account in Azure which I am trying to access using Microsoft Fabric Dataflow Gen2. I managed to connect to the storage account using a vnet data gateway.
Getting the data results in a query that has the following columns:



Content
Name
Extension
Date accessed
Date modified
Date created
Attributes
Folder path




[Binary]
Iris.parquet
.parquet
null
5/29/2024, 8:04:02 AM
null
[Record]
https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer


[Binary]
MT cars.parquet
.parquet
null
5/29/2024, 8:04:02 AM
null
[Record]
https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer


[Binary]
Titanic.parquet
.parquet
null
5/29/2024, 8:04:02 AM
null
[Record]
https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer



Now imagine I have 100 parquet files, I do not want to do a navigation and convert from parquet for each row I have. I want to load them all into a lakehouse as bronze layer. How can I turn this query into all the different tables (in the example, 3 different tables) and load them into a lakehouse?

Instead of using the VNET Data Gateway, configure Trusted Workspace Access for your Storage Account, and simply create shortcut to the storage account in the Files section of your Fabric Lakehouse.
Alternatively, use a Fabric or ADF Pipeline to copy the files in binary mode into OneLake.
Or just use azcopy to read from ALDS and write to OneLake.
In short Dataflows Gen 2 is the wrong tool for this task.

Hi David, I agree Dataflows are the wrong tool. But since pipelines and shortcuts dont support VNET Data Gateways I had to resort to this tool. But I did not know about Trusted Workspace Access. I will try this solution and mark your answer as the solution if this works for me. Thank you for your help.
